# Iterate through specific column in data set

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python here. I have a large data set (1129 rows x 319 columns) and i want to iterate through a specific column. If one of the rows in the column has the string i am looking for, i would like to append that whole row into another dataset.

In the image, I would like to append the rows containing `'Private non-financial sector'` into a new dataset. Some guidance would be much appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2INbW.png)

Comment: please provide enough code so that we can play with it - include data as well. dont post pictures: read http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  -  I am willing to help, I am not willing to retype 50 lines of code on _my time_ that you simply can copy&paste. Indent code by 4 spaces to make it look like code - make sure your indentation is correct after posting.

Comment: if you use pandas or stmh similar, add is as tag as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the below solution:

suppose new Dataframe is new_df in which you want to store the specifiead column and df is the current dataframe:

new_df=df[df['Borrowig sector']=='Private non-financial sector']

Then the new_df will contain the needed data!